Float8 embeddings returned by querying Milvus python client
I am using the Attu client to manage the data from Milvus and all the data looks good inside.
But when i am trying to query the same data with the python client, the embeddings results i get are in a float8 format instead of a float32 one.
Why is that? Is there a limitation or conversion on the retrieval process?
Here is a snippet of the query i am running:
self.milvusClient.query(
    collection_name='someCollection',
    output_fields=['embedding'],
    filter='objectId in [' +  ','.join(objectIdList) + ']',
    limit=limit
)

Also here is a snippet of the creation command for the embedding field:

schema.add_field(field_name="embedding", datatype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=512, is_primary=False, auto_id=False)

index_params.add_index(
    field_name="embedding", 
    index_type="IVF_FLAT",
    metric_type="L2",
    params={
        "nlist": 2048
    }
)

Value stored: -0.24403861165046692
Value retrieved: -0.24403861
Thank you!

The same discussions might answer the question:

https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/discussions/32737
https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/discussions/32224

In short: A Float32 value has a precision of ~7 decimal digits. Even with a Float64 value, such as 1.3476964684980388, Milvus stores it as 1.347696.

Float vectors are in fact stored and computed using the float32 data type in Milvus with a default storage with a precision of about 7 decimal digits.
However, in Python, standard float values are processed as float64. When float64 values are passed to Milvus, the SDK automatically converts them to float32, and the values are returned as float32 as well when being retrieved.
There are several reasons for using float32 instead of float64 in approximate nearest neighbor (ANN) search:

Memory and Storage Efficiency: Float64 consumes more memory and disk space compared to float32.
Computation Speed: CPUs compute float64 operations much slower than float32 operations.
Result Accuracy: ANN search is an approximate search method, and the difference in results between using float32 and float64 is negligible.

